# Adding Admob into ScrollView -> AdBanner disappears

Tags: android, scrollview, admob, banner

Hey folks
I managed to implement Admob  into a normal linear layout so far.
Now I added a additional `scrollview` and the `adbanner` disappeared. I don´t know what I can do against it.

Follows the code from the .xml where I added the `scrollview`:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent"   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

     [whole bunch of layout elements whoch shouldn´t affect the adbanner]

     </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

In my linear layout ,where the adbanner still works, the whole adbanner position was done in the main activitiy.java file (did this with help of the tutorial at taiic.com)

```
    // Lookup R.layout.main
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); 

    // Create the adView
    // Please replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with your AdMob Publisher ID
    String pubID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, pubID);

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);

    adView.loadAd(request);
```

Can anybody tell me what to change or what code to add when implementing an admob banner into a `scrollview`?

edit:

i tried to add

```
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/ad"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
myapprimaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
android:alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

between last two lines in the .xml

```
  </LinearLayout>
     [here]
  </ScrollView>
```

but then im getting the error "error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix"

cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## About the parsing error:

Is this a typo in the question? `myapprimaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"` instead of `myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"` . This would give you the xml parse error.

---

## About the layouts:

Use a RelativeLayout. **The working code is at the end of the post. First, some theory :)**

Your ScrollView is taking the whole screen, that's why you don't see the admob view. When the scrollview is defined, all the screen is availabel to it, so it takes it. The admob view is actually drawn *below* your screen. It can be reproduced in this example:

**non-working layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent">
         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:orientation="vertical"
         >
            <EditText  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="300dp" 
            android:text="Test1"
            />
            <EditText  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="300dp" 
            android:text="Test2"
            />
            <EditText  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="300dp" 
            android:text="Test3"
            />
         </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>    
        <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Test4"
        />
   </LinearLayout>
```

If you use a RelativeLayout instead, you can set it up so the admob is aligned to the bottom of the screen, and the scrollview above it, taking the rest of the available space.

**working layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Test4"
        android:id="@+id/test4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
       <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_above="@id/test4"
           >
         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:orientation="vertical"
         >
            <EditText  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="300dp" 
            android:text="Test1"
            />
            <EditText  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="300dp" 
            android:text="Test2"
            />
            <EditText  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="300dp" 
            android:text="Test3"
            />
         </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>    
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: had this typo in my source code aswell, but fixing it didn´t change anything.

Comment: Do you still have the parsing error? Do you have `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in your first layout?

Comment: in my .java file, which is connected to the .xml file, the AdView requires : LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); .    but when i use your working code, do i have to change everything with "linearLayout"  to "RelativeLayout"? i tried your code and the app crashes because the AdView cant find the told linearLayout id

Comment: changed it now to RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);  in the .java file and added android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout" to your code, but the app still crashes when starting the activity :(             (going to bed now, will answer tomorrow, good night)

Comment: Can't see how this is the answer - you state you did not change the Java code, but with the 'working layout', you won't even be able to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I used the admob xml version and that is what I use and it works. The ad is at the top. Just copy and paste and you will be scrolling along shortly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yourproject.here"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adUnitId="a14dc1c9d6xxxxx"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER" />

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true" > 

        [whole bunch of layout elements whoch shouldn´t affect the adbanner]

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yourproject.here"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adUnitId="a14dc1c9d6xxxxx"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER" />

Comment: You can Edit your answer if you need to fix it, that way it will be formatted and appear immediately.